# Push Back in Map

Tags: c++, vector, containers, push-back

Is there any possibility to use `push_back()` in maps?

I want to make a `map < int, vector<string>>` and fill the `vector` in a loop with strings.

It should look something like this:

```
map[int] = vector.push_back(string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `push_back` into the `vector` returned by `map[N]`, just use:

```
//assuming
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> my_map;
int N;
std::string my_string;

my_map[N].push_back(my_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map by Default accepts two any same or different datatypes. So, for inserting a vector of strings:

```
map<int, vector<string>> mp;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int k; cin>>k;
    string str; cin>>str;
    mp[k].push_back(str);
}
```